# Filtering DSL Query Search - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, querydsl

I was reading a few articles and documents over query context and filter context and learned that it is always best to use filter context if you do not need to do a full text search or scoring does not matter. **In my case, I am wanting to return the logs that contain an ID... so I then realized I should just use a filter context instead of a query context. Besides the full text search or scoring is there a hard base line that defines when you should use one over the other?**

So I went from my original DSL query search cmd:

```
GET /customer-simulation-es-app-logs*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_id": "mJvG0nkBiU3wk_hrEd-8"
    }
  }
```

to the filter context:

```
GET /customer-simulation-es-app-logs*/_search
{
  
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"match": {"_id": "mJvG0nkBiU3wk_hrEd-8"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
}
```

Since, I am wanting to use NEST to perform the query search I took this approach.

```
    [HttpGet("GetAll/{_id}")]
    public async Task<EsSource> GetAll(String _id)
    {
        var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsSource>(s => s
            .Index("customer-simulation-es-app-logs*")
            .Query(q => q
                 .Bool(b => b
                   .Filter(f => f
                      .Match(m => m.Field("_id").Query(_id))))));

        return response?.Documents?.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

**Would this be the correct way to do a `filter context` using NEST?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the correct way to issue a query with only a filter context. Some additional points that might help

1. A [term-level query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-level-queries.html) on the `_id` field, like a [`term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) should suffice, as there's no analysis chain involved
2. If you know the index that contains the document, the [get API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html) would be a better option. Given a wildcard index pattern is being used though, implies that the index might not be known.
3. NEST has [convenient operator overloads on queries to make writing bool queries more succinct](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html). The final query can be written more succinctly as

```cs
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsSource>(s => s
    .Index("customer-simulation-es-app-logs*")
    .Query(q => +q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("_id")
            .Query(_id)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation and pointers!